# Code Runs in Console but not with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I have a model that describes a patient (a Packet) which references the destination hospital and the transporting ambulance:

```
class Packet < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :hospital
 belongs_to :provider
 validates_presence_of :hospital_id
 validates_presence_of :provider_id
end 

class Hospital < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :packets
end

class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :packets
end
```

and my RSpec specification:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe Packet, :type => :model do
  it "creates a new packet" do
    hospital = Hospital.create(:name=>"Community Hospital")
    provider = Provider.create(:name=>"Community Ambulance", :unit=>"Ambulance 3")

    packet = Packet.new()
    packet.hospital = hospital
    packet.provider = provider
    packet.save
    end
  end
```

RSpec fails with:
      1) Packet creates a new packet
      Failure/Error: packet.hospital = hospital
      ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError:
        can't write unknown attribute `hospital_id`

The thing I don't get is that the meat of my test (everything in the "it" block) runs fine in the rails console, with no errors.  Why would I get the unknown attribute in the rspec test but not in the console?

Full stack trace:
    Garys-MacBook-Air-2:EMSPacket gary$ rspec
    F

```
Failures:

1) Packet creates a new packet
    Failure/Error: packet.hospital = hospital
    ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError:
    can't write unknown attribute `hospital_id`
# /Users/gary/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute.rb:124:in `with_value_from_database'
# /Users/gary/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_set.rb:39:in `write_from_user'
# /Users/gary/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:74:in `write_attribute_with_type_cast'
# /Users/gary/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:56:in `write_attribute'
# /Users/gary/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:92:in `write_attribute'
# /Users/gary/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:373:in `[]='
# /Users/gary/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb:80:in `replace_keys'
# /Users/gary/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb:14:in `replace'
# /Users/gary/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/singular_association.rb:17:in `writer'
# /Users/gary/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:123:in `hospital='
# ./spec/models/packet_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.14495 seconds (files took 7.49 seconds to load)
```

1 example, 1 failure

```
Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/packet_spec.rb:4 # Packet creates a new packet
```

Comment: Paste full stack trace of errors.

Comment: Try running the same code in the console but with test environment: "RAILS_ENV=test rails console" . If this fails, then you didn't migrate your database. "rake db:test:prepare"

Comment: Jorge, thank you.   It was the test db

Answer (score 1):

RSpec is trying to test everystep inside the it block, that's why the test is failing but the console works. You have to create the record with the attributes and relations before testing it, and then test something.

The code you pasted for the tests id not actually testing anything.

Try to tests things that can really fail, like saving with errors, or creating without associations. But not repeating the steps inside the test.

```
describe "When creating new package" do
  let(:hospital) {Hospital.create(attributes)}
  let(:provider) {Provider.create(attributes)}
  let(:packet) {Packet.create(hospital_id: hospital.id, provider_id: provider.id)}

  it "should have the associations linked" do
    expect(package.hospital_id).to eq(hospital.id)
    expect(package.provider_id).to eq(provider.id)
  end
end
```

EDITED:

Remember to run your migrations for the test database:

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

Comment: But I am creating the records with attributes.   I'm using a Hospital.create() just as you are.   I know that my code is not actually testing anything.  I stripped out all the expect() code.   I did paste your code (with some minor corrections) and I still get  "unknown attribute 'hospital_id' for Packet."

Comment: Edited with the proper answer after the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers in my tests

it would be

```
describe 'associations' do
  it { should belong_to :hospital }
  it { should belong_to :provider }
end


describe 'validations' do
  it { should validate_presence_of :hospital_id }
  it { should validate_presence_of :provider_id }
end
```

Anyway take a look at https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl, it will help you with tests also.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to  Jorge de los Santos, the problem was the setup of my test database.   Thanks Jorge!